# Accents and 'ç' do not show in case ... when - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a case ... when in SQL and the accents and 'ç' do not appear for example:

```
CASE Example WHEN '1' THEN 'Exampleç' WHEN '2' THEN 'Exampleáé' END
```

This show: `Example?` and `Example`

I want show accents and 'ç'

Comment: Perhaps `n'Exampleç'`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data which requires an extended character set, then change the collation of your table or database to support this, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

For a temporary fix, you could try collating the particular `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE Example WHEN '1' THEN 'Exampleç'
                 WHEN '2' THEN 'Exampleáé' END COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci AS some_col
FROM yourTable
```